# ElasticSearch - Compare distinct values over two time periods

Tags: elasticsearch

Struggling with the following problem - 
I have a huge dataset in ElasticSearch, and I want to compare distinct IDs over two time periods.

Here's a simple example so you'll better understand what I mean:
The following data was sent in the last 24 hours:

```
{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}
```

and this data was send over the 24 hours a week ago:

```
{id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}
```

I want to output:

```
1, 4
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bucket selector aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html) can be used to select fields which are present in one interval but not in other

I have taken a data set of three documents with unique id 1 and 2. Id 1 is present on date "2020-04-22" and "2020-04-23" while Id 2 is present only on "2020-04-23". So query should return only Id 2

**Data:**

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index21",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "N48Xp3EB1jFeu7E5np_U",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 1,
          "date" : "2020-04-23"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index21",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "OI8Xp3EB1jFeu7E5z5-5",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 1,
          "date" : "2020-04-22"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index21",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "OY8Yp3EB1jFeu7E5GJ_V",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 2,
          "date" : "2020-04-23"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Using [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) get all unique id. Under each term find document count in different interval. Select terms which have 0 count in either of interval.

```
 Terms      1
              "2020-04-22"  1(doc count)
              "2020-04-23"  1(doc count)
            2 
              "2020-04-22"  0(doc count)    
              "2020-04-23"  1(doc count)

  Select term 2
```

**Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "ids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "document_first_interval": {
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "date": {
                "gte": "2020-04-23"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "document_second_interval": {
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "date": {
                "gte": "2020-04-22",
                "lt": "2020-04-23"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "select_bucket": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "first_interval": "document_first_interval._count",
              "second_interval": "document_second_interval._count"
            },
            "script": "if(params.first_interval==0||params.second_interval==0) return true;"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Giving the result:**

```
"aggregations" : {
    "ids" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 2,
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "document_second_interval" : {
            "doc_count" : 0
          },
          "document_first_interval" : {
            "doc_count" : 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Glad could be of help:)

Comment: Hi Jaspreet, would this solution work if I had approximately 1 million unique ids? or would it get limited by the 10k results that Elastic can display?

Comment: @KelvinDucray, default value for  max_result_window is 10k. You can change the value in settings with downside of slowing down the cluster. Better alternative will be to try out composite aggregation but you won't be able to use bucket selector in that case